# Positive semidefinite matrix using Schur Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, schur-complement

Let

$$ G =\begin{pmatrix} \Sigma & \Sigma - \text{diag} \lbrace s \rbrace \\ \Sigma - \text{diag} \lbrace s \rbrace & \Sigma \end{pmatrix} $$

where $s \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^p$ is some nonnegative vector, and $\Sigma$ is a positive definite covariance matrix.

I need to argue that $G$ is positive semidefinite using the Schur complement. That is, $G$ is positive semidefinite iff the Schur complement
$$
2\text{diag} \lbrace s \rbrace-\text{diag} \lbrace s \rbrace \Sigma^{-1} \text{diag} \lbrace s \rbrace
$$
is positive semidefinite. However I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Is $s \geq 0_p$?

Comment: It is not possible to say anything without more information on $s$. Take e.g. $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1-s\\1-s & 1\end{bmatrix}$. It is psd iff $0\le s\le 2$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - s is a nonnegative vector.

Comment: We can assume that $\Sigma$ is invertible. And since it is a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite and symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write down the nonstrict version of the Schur complement formula

$$
G\succeq 0 \iff \left\{\begin{array}{cc}\Sigma\succeq 0\\ \Sigma-(\Sigma-\textrm{diag}(s))\Sigma^{\dagger}(\Sigma-\textrm{diag}(s))\succeq0\\ (I-\Sigma\Sigma^\dagger)(\Sigma-\textrm{diag}(s))=0\end{array}\right.
$$
The second condition expands to
$$
\Sigma-(\Sigma-\textrm{diag}(s))\Sigma^{\dagger}(\Sigma-\textrm{diag}(s))= \textrm{diag}(s)\Sigma^{\dagger}\Sigma + \Sigma\Sigma^{\dagger}\textrm{diag}(s)-\textrm{diag}(s)\Sigma^{\dagger}\textrm{diag}(s)
$$
if $\Sigma$ is also invertible then you are done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I am not sure that I understand the last step. Why is the last matrix positive semidefinite if $\Sigma$ is invertible?

Comment: @mathstudent $\Sigma\Sigma^\dagger$ will be $I$ matrix.